# How to get encoded data in node.js?

Tags: node.js, utf

When I submit the html form getting post data in server side and when I console my data is displayed like **hemant%40gmail.com** this is my server side code:

```
         if(req.url=="/user_login"){
             var logindata='';
            req.on('data',function(data){
                logindata+=data;

            });
            req.on('end',function(){
              console.log(logindata);

            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what u really want, but with JavaScript you can do:

```
logindata += decodeURI(data);
```

Hope u just need to decode your encoded string?!

// update
ok u have to use "decodeURIComponent(data)" to decode your string.

here is an example:

```
var test = '"user_email=hemant%40gmail.com&password=111'
var decode = decodeURIComponent(test).split("=")[1].split("&")[0]
console.log(decode);
```

**note:** this is an easy example, u have to parse to get your email out of the string (use regex).

Comment: see console logindata  it displayed like "user_email=hemant%40gmail.com&password=111" i want hemant@gmail.com

Comment: ok, try the "decodeURI(data)" to clean the encoded characters. if you want to remove "user_email=" you have to use JavaScript ".split()" like: "decodeURI(data).split("=")[1]".